# Why are orthogonal polynomials "unique"?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-methods

I am reading *Numerical Analysis* by Walter Gautschi, and the autor says (I quote):

> [Talks about $\{1, t, t^2, ..., t^n \}$] Since a linearly independent set can be orthogonalized by Gram-Schmidt, any measure $d \lambda$ of the type considered generates a **unique** [emphasis mine] set of (monic) orthogonal polynomials $\pi_j(t) = \pi_j(t; d \lambda)$, $j=0, 1, 2, ...,$ satisfying
>
> $$\deg \pi_j = j, j = 0, 1, 2, ...,$$
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \pi_k(t) \pi_{\ell}(t) d \lambda (t) = 0 \text{ if } t \not = \ell.$$
>
> There are called *orthogonal polynomials* relative to the measure $d \lambda$.

From what I understand, the author is saying that (for example) if we take the space spanned by $1, t, t^2$ and we have a fixed inner product $(u, v) = \int_a^b u(t)v(t)w(t) dt$, then there exists a unique set of three monic, orthogonal polynomials which span this space. Furthermore, the author seems to say that this follows directly from the Gram-Schmidt process.

I can sort of see a reason why these polynomials are unique; having made an orthogonal set $\{p_0, p_1, ..., p_{n-1} \}$ of $n$ polynomials, we want the $p_{n}$ (which has $n+1$ coefficients) to satisfy
$$(p_k, p_n) = 0 \text{ for } k = 0, 1, ..., n-1$$
$$\text{leading coefficient = 1}$$

which is a system of $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ variables, so it *could* just have a unique solution. But I don't see why this system has to be non-singular.

Comment: What is "measure of the type considered" in this context?

Comment: @kimchilover It is the measure corresponding to a weight function with support $[a, b]$ or a weight function whose support is a finite set of points.

Comment: If $$\int_a^bw(t)p_3(t)t^k=0$$ for $k\in\{0,1,2\}$, $p_3^{\prime\prime\prime}(t)=6$, $p_3(t_1)=p_3(t_2)=p_3(t_3)=0$ then $$\left\{\frac{p_3(t)}{t-t_1},\frac{p_3(t)}{t-t_2},\frac{p_3(t)}{t-t_3}\right\}$$ is a monic orthogonal basis of $\mathcal{P}_2$. The constraint that $\deg \pi_j=j$ is what makes it unique.

Comment: This question is more on the Gram-Schmidt algorithm in general than it is on orthogonal polynomials. Indeed, the set of vectors produced by Gram-Schmidt always satisfies a uniqueness property, which is exactly the one you need here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missread the line, which is not written to well.

What the line is probably saing is the following: You have a vector space $V = \mbox{span} \{ 1, t,.., t^n \}$ and an inner product for this space, $ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} p(t) q(t) d \lambda(t)$.

Now, in this situation, **given any ordered basis** (in this case $(1,t,.., t^n)$) the GS produces an unique ONB.

But if you change the basis , or even their order, you would generally get a different set with the same properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I may ask, regarding your last sentence, are you sure we will get a dfferent set? The other answer and the comment seem to say no. I did Gram-Schmidt manually on $\{1, t-2, t^2+4t-3 \}$ with uniform weight on $[-1, 1]$, and I got the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: @Blue I made the last paragraph more clear. In general, you will get the Legendre polynomials exactly when your polynomials are monic and of degrees 0,1,2,3,..  and so on. For GS, two sets $\{ u_1,.., u_n \}$ and $\{ v_1,.., v_n \}$ give you the same answer if and only if $$v_1=u_1 \\ v_2=u_2-\alpha_1u_1 \\...\ v_k = u_k-\beta_1u_1-...-\beta_{k-1}u_{k-1}$$

Comment: If you also do normalisation, $\{ u_1,.., u_n \}$ and $\{ v_1,.., v_n \}$ give you the same answer after normalisation if and only if, for each $k$ you have $v_k \in \mbox{Span} \{ u_1,.., u_k \}$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the powers of $t$ are linearly independent you know it cannot be singular.  When you orthogonalize the powers up to $t^k$ they still span the space with basis $\{1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^k\}$.  $t^{k+1}$ cannot be dependent on these, so the process continues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am having a little trouble understanding it. So suppose we have $n$ orthogonal, monic polynomials $p_0, ..., p_{n-1}$ with $\deg p_j = j$. The $n+1$ equations become, for $0 \le k \le n,$ $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j (x^j, p_k(x))$, with $a_n=1$, so the associated (non-augmented) matrix for the (for example) $3 \times 3$ case is

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}  
(1, p_0(x)) & (x, p_0(x)) & (x^2, p_0(x))\\ 
(1, p_1(x)) & (x, p_1(x)) & (x^2, p_1(x))\\ 
(1, p_2(x)) & (x, p_2(x)) & (x^2, p_2(x))\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Why can't this matrix be singular?